# Summation of infinite series with hyperbolic sine

Tags: sequences-and-series

The following is a conjecture.

I would like to prove that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)\operatorname{sinh}((2n+1)\pi)}=\frac{\log(2)}{8}.$$

Both sides agree to at least $100$ digits, so I suspect the identity is true. I have thought about expanding $1/\operatorname{sinh}$ as a series and switching the summation, but I can't get this to work.

Comment: So you computed the lhs up to 100 digits and then guessed that it would be equal to rhs?

Comment: @julien Yes. $ $

Comment: Wow, I'll believe you then!

Comment: [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B1%2F%28%282n%2B1%29+sinh%28%282n%2B1%29+pi%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C+0%2C+infinity%7D%5D%3D%3Dlog%282%29%2F8) seems to agree with the conjecture.

Comment: Does Wolfram do it algebraically, or numerically?

Comment: $1/\sinh x=2/(e^x-e^{-x})=2e^{-x}/(1-e^{-2x})=2e^{-x}(1+e^{-2x}+e^{-4x}+\cdots$. I don't know, maybe that will help.

Comment: Using Gerry's expansions and exchanging summations leads to $2 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tanh^{-1}\left(e^{-\pi(2k+1)}\right)$. Does not really help though. Euler-Maclaurin diverges and I don't know the formulas @Ethan is refering to...

Comment: @Ethan thanks for the link.

Comment: I wish I could remember what motivated this...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One of the references in the paper Ethan mentions is:

> "Some Infinite Series of Exponential and Hyperbolic Functions", I. J. Zucker,
>   SIAM Journal on Mathematical Analysis **15** (1984), 406-413, DOI [10.1137/0515031](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0515031).

In Table 1, this paper has a number of equations similar to the identity the questioner gives; in fact, this identity can be gotten from Table 1 by subtracting (T1.3) from (T1.4) and substituting $k=k'=1/\sqrt{2}$, $c=1$.  Here, $k$, $k'$, $c$, and $q$ (to appear momentarily) are parameters of the lattice for a doubly periodic function and are related by
$$
k^2+k'^2=1, \qquad c=\frac{K(k')}{K(k)},\qquad q=e^{-\pi c}
$$
where
$$
K(k)=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)(1-k^2 x^2)}} \, dx
$$
is the complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

The method Zucker uses to prove the identities in Table 1 is to take the logarithm of the product representation of a product of [theta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), expand the logarithm, and then rearrange the sum.  To use this method to prove the questioner's identity, start from the following identity (derived from pp. 469, 479, Whittaker & Watson, 4th edition):
$$
\frac{\theta_4(0,q)}{\theta_3(0,q)}=\sqrt{k'}=\prod_{n\ge 1} \frac{(1-q^{2n-1})^2}{(1+q^{2n-1})^2}.
$$
Taking logarithms and expanding the logarithm as a power series gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \log k'&=&\sum_{n, m\ge 1} \frac4m((-1)^m-1)q^{(2n-1)m}\\
&=&-\sum_{n\ge1,\ m\ge 0} \frac{8}{2m+1}q^{(2n-1)(2m+1)}\\
&=&-4\sum_{m\ge 0} \frac{1}{2m+1} \frac{2}{q^{-(2m+1)}-q^{2m+1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Set $k=k'=1/\sqrt{2}$; then $q=e^{-\pi}$.  This gives the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a proof of your identity, but some resources you can use to probably prove it.

Re-writing the hyperbolic function in terms of exponentials and using some partial fraction decomposition, allows you to re-write that identity as,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)(e^{\pi(2n+1)}-1)}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2n+1)(e^{\pi(2n+1)}+1)}=\frac{\ln(2)}{8}$$

Which should look alot like many Plouffe/Ramanujan identities,

If you have ever seen Ramanujan's identity, $$\zeta(3)=\frac{7\pi^3}{180}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3(e^{2\pi n}-1)}$$
And similar identitys involving logarithm constants and lambert series' are given at the bottom of:
(http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalLogarithm.html)

For your particular identity if you use some of the identities proven here,
 (http://www.linas.org/math/plouffe-ram.pdf)

You can probably prove your identity.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I attempted using residues, as I expressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304681/summation-using-residues).  Once it was pointed out to me my mistake, I went to work and set up another sum based on the infinite set of residues along the line $\Re{z} = -1/2$.  It turns out that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)\operatorname{sinh}((2n+1)\pi)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n} \tanh{\left ( \pi \frac{n}{2} \right )}$$

You can verify this in Mathematica or elsewhere.  Unfortunately, I seemed to have swapped one tough sum for another.  Sigh.