# How to prove that $4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos(n\pi)}{n\sinh(n\pi)}=\ln2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This problem is equal to prove that 
$$8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n-1)\sinh((2n-1)\pi)}=\ln2$$
I try to use Fourier transform but failed,how to deal with it?

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304390/515527 (I missclicked when I tried to mark it as a duplicate and now it shows this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/304681/515527).