# How to compute $\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{1}{n\sinh n\pi\sqrt 3}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

I came across an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/576318/73025) asking to show that $$\displaystyle\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{1}{n\sinh n\pi}=\frac{\ln 2}{8}.\tag{1}$$
Although I have managed to prove this formula, [my proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1330116/73025) uses various theta functional relations and looks like an overkill. On the other hand, it suggests a few more identities, for example
$$\displaystyle\sum_{n\text{ odd}}\frac{1}{n\sinh n\pi\sqrt3}=\frac{\ln \left(8-4\sqrt{3}\right)}{4}.\tag{2}$$

---

**Question**: can one prove (1) and (2) in a more elementary way? Ideally, the proof should make clear further generalizations.

Comment: Have you tried using the identity $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+m^2}=\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{\pi}{2m \sinh(m\pi)}$$ ?

Comment: That gives that the problem is related with the ways in which we may represent an integer via the binary quadratic forms $a^2+b^2$ or $a^2+3b^2$. We have class number one in both cases.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio No I didn't think of this,but this may be useful indeed. The only vague idea I had before asking was to use the Poisson summation formula in some way (this is inspired by its use in the proof of the Jacobi imaginary transformation; the hope was to convert $\sinh$'s into $\sin$'s somehow).

Comment: So far I only managed to derive the identity
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\left[\frac{1}{n\sinh(n\pi u\sqrt{2})}+\frac{1}{n\sinh(\frac{n\pi\sqrt{2}}{u})}\right]=\frac{\pi\cosh(\ln{u})}{3\sqrt{2}}-\ln{2}$$

Comment: $$
\sum_{n\ \mathrm{odd}}{1 \over n \sinh\left(n\pi\right)} =
{\ln\left(2\right) \over \color{#f00}{4}} \approx 0.1733
$$

Comment: @FelixMarin I think the denominator is $8$, not $4$.

Answer (score 19):

The identities:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+m^2} = -\frac{1}{2m^2}+\frac{\pi}{2m\sinh(m\pi)},\tag{A}$$
$$ \frac{1}{m^2+n^2}=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}e^{-mx}\,dx,\tag{B}$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}(-1)^n\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}=-\frac{x}{2}+\pi\left\lfloor\frac{x+\pi}{2\pi}\right\rfloor\tag{C} $$
give a wide range of possibilities to evaluate our series. For instance, $(A)$ gives:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)\sinh(\pi(2k+1))}&=&\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+(2k+1)^2}\\&=&-\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{h\geq 1}\frac{r_2(h)\cdot\eta(h)}{h}\tag{1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
where $\eta(h)$ equals $-1$ if $h\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, $1$ if $h\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, zero otherwise, and:
$$ r_2(h) = \#\{(n,k)\in\mathbb{N}^2: h=n^2+(2k+1)^2\}.\tag{2} $$
Now it is well-known that $a^2+b^2$ is the only reduced binary quadratic form of discriminant $-4$, hence:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \#\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}:a^2+b^2=n\} &=& 4\left(\chi_4 * 1\right)(n)\\&=& 4\left(d_{1(4)}(n)-d_{3(4)}(n)\right) \tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
so that we can evaluate the RHS of $(1)$ through Dirichlet convolution.

Since we have class number one also in the case $a^2+3b^2$, the situation is almost the same for the other series.

The Mellin transform gives another chance. See, for instance, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330213/calculating-in-closed-form-sum-n-1-infty-sum-m-1-infty-frac1m4/1330250#1330250) related problem.

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** This is not a complete answer, but it includes some observations that can possibly be developed further.

---

**Contour Integral Representation of ${\rm Li}_\nu(e^{-x})$**

By Mellin's inversion theorem, the polylogarithm admits the contour integral representation
$${\rm Li}_\nu(e^{-x})=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{c+i\infty}_{c-i\infty}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s+\nu)x^{-s}\ {\rm d}s$$

---

**The Sum $S(\mu)$ as a Contour Integral**

Switching the order of summation, we may write
$$S(\mu)\stackrel{\text{def}}=:\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n\sinh(n\mu)}=2\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k\ge0}e^{-(2k+1)n\mu}=2\sum_{k\ge0}{\rm Li}_1\left(e^{-(2k+1)\mu}\right)$$
Therefore, the sum can be expressed as a contour integral
$$S(\mu)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{c+i\infty}_{c-i\infty}Q(s,\mu)\ {\rm d}s$$
where 
\begin{align}
Q(s,\mu)
&=2\mu^{-s}(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)\\
\end{align}

---

**Closing the Contour**

We instead consider the integral of $\dfrac{Q(s,\mu)}{2\pi i}$ over a closed contour $C$. In this case, it is a rectangle with vertices $\frac{3}{2}-i\infty$, $\frac{3}{2}+i\infty$, $-\frac{3}{2}+i\infty$, $-\frac{3}{2}-i\infty$. Note that

1. The integral over $\mathrm{Re}(s)=\frac{3}{2}$ is $S(\mu)$.
2. The integral over the horizontal sides vanishes since $\zeta(s)$ grows moderately but $\Gamma(s)$ decays exponentially as $\mathrm{Im}(s)\to-\infty$.
3. Applying Riemann's functional equation twice, the integral over $\mathrm{Re}(s)=-\frac{3}{2}$ is shown to be:

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{-\frac{3}{2}+i\infty}_{-\frac{3}{2}-i\infty}Q(\mu,s)\ {\rm d}s
&=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{-\frac{3}{2}+i\infty}_{-\frac{3}{2}-i\infty}2\left(\frac{\mu}{4\pi^2}\right)^{-s}(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(-s)\zeta(-s)\zeta(1-s)\ {\rm d}s\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int^{\frac{3}{2}+i\infty}_{\frac{3}{2}-i\infty}2\left(\frac{2\pi^2}{\mu}\right)^{-s}(1-2^{-s})\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)\zeta(s+1)\ {\rm d}s\\
\end{align}
which is equal to $\displaystyle S\left(\frac{2\pi^2}{\mu}\right)$.

---

**Functional Equation for $S(\mu)$**

By the residue theorem,
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C Q(s,\mu)\ {\rm d}s=\sum^1_{k=-1}{\rm Res}(Q(s,\mu);z=k)=\frac{\pi^2}{6\mu}-\ln{2}+\frac{\mu}{12}
\end{align}
Thus $S(\mu)$ satisfies the functional equation
$$S(\pi\mu\sqrt{2})+S\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{\mu}\right)=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{2}}\left(\mu+\frac{1}{\mu}\right)-\ln{2}$$
For instance, this equation yields the identity
$$\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n\sinh(n\pi\sqrt{2})}=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln{2}}{2}$$

---

**Conjectured form of $S(\mu)$**

We are actually interested in the quantity $S\left(\pi\right)-\dfrac{1}{2}S(2\pi)$. It is likely that $S(\pi\mu\sqrt{2})$ is of the form
$$S(\pi\sqrt{2}\mu)\stackrel{?}=\frac{\pi}{6\sqrt{2}}\mu-\frac{\ln{2}}{2}+f(\mu)\tag1$$
such that $f(\mu)=-f(\mu^{-1})$, $f(0)$ blows up, and $f\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\stackrel{?}=\dfrac{\ln{2}}{4}$. If this is truly the case, then we indeed get
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ \text{odd}}\frac{1}{n\sinh(n\pi)}
&=S(\pi)-\frac{1}{2}S(2\pi)\\\
&=\left(\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{\ln{2}}{2}+\frac{\ln{2}}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{6}-\frac{\ln{2}}{2}-\frac{\ln{2}}{4}\right)\\
&=\frac{\ln{2}}{8}
\end{align}
which of course implies that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{n\sinh(n\pi)}=\frac{\pi}{12}-\frac{\ln{2}}{4}$. Numerically, this seems to be true.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove or disprove $(1)$ and find the correct $f(\mu)$.

Answer (score -2):

Don't forget that `sinh` is an odd function, so we can use
$$
n \, sinh(n \pi) = -n \, sinh(-n \pi)
$$
to reduce the summation to
$$
\sum_{n\in2\Bbb Z+1}\frac{1}{n\,sinh(n\pi)} = \sum_{n\in2\Bbb N+1}\frac{1}{n\,sinh(n\pi)}
$$
which is more directly manipulated (without having to play with summation indices) if written anyway as
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n+1)\,sinh((2n+1)\pi)}
$$

Not really sure how to simplify to your end, from here, but perhaps this is helpful anyway.

-Cheers

Comment: Of course, it's trivial. However it may turn out that the summation over $2\mathbb{Z}+1$ is more suitable (I had in mind something like Poisson summation).