# How to calculate this sum: $\sum_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\sinh(kn))^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I encountered this summation in Statistical Mechanics. 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(\sinh(kn))^3}$$ I know this series converges. Can we find its closed form solution? Here k is some positive real number.

Comment: What is the sum over, $k$ or $n$?

Comment: For particular values of $k$, this series has a closed form in terms of [elliptic singular values](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html). See *Zucker, The Summation of Series of Hyperbolic Functions*. See also this related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304390/summation-of-infinite-series-with-hyperbolic-sine

Comment: Approximate it. The first term dominates the sum so to first order it's $\frac{1}{\sinh(k)^3}$. This is a perfect approximation for large $k$. For small $k < 1$ it's off by $10\%$.